# Apply attribute to macro expansion

Tags: rust

I'm using macros to generate tests. Imagine a simple definition like this:

```rust
macro_rules! my_test {
    ($name:ident) => {
       #[test]
       fn $name() {
         assert_eq!(6, 3 + 3);
       }
    };
}
```

I would like to disable some of the tests I generated this way:

```rust
my_test!(good_test_a);

my_test!(good_test_b);

#[ignore]
my_test!(bad_test_a);

#[ignore]
my_test!(bad_test_b);
```

However, according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57679#issuecomment-455127560),

> attributes applied to macro calls are eliminated during expansion of the macro.

And indeed, all of the tests run; none is ignored. (See [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48e8ab795db10ffa45daac8cea08eac6).)

Is there any practical workaround for this limitation? Is there perhaps some other way of invoking the macro that would allow the `#[ignore]` attribute to be applied to its expansion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any practical workaround for this limitation?

Yes. By allowing the macro itself to accept attributes through the [`meta` macro fragment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/macros-by-example.html) you can work around the problem like so:

```
#![cfg(test)]

macro_rules! my_test {
    ($(#[$m:meta])* // This accepts `#[foo] #[bar(..)] ..`
     $name:ident) => {
       $(#[$m])* // This expands the attributes.
       #[test]
       fn $name() {
         assert_eq!(6, 3 + 3);
       }
    };
}

my_test!(good_test_a);

my_test!(good_test_b);

// You can pass in `#[ignore]` or any series of attributes you wish:
my_test!(#[ignore] bad_test_a);

my_test!(#[ignore] bad_test_b);
```

Running this, we get:

```
running 4 tests
test bad_test_a ... ignored
test bad_test_b ... ignored
test good_test_a ... ok
test good_test_b ... ok

test result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 2 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```