# I want to define a test function in a macro and possibly add #[should_panic] attribute

Tags: rust

I want to define a function in a macro variant and give it #[should_panic] or #[test] attribute depending on the condition.

```rust
macro_rules! impl_test {
    ($fn_name:ident, $shape:expr, $axis:expr, $ans:expr) => {
        fn $fn_name() {
            // do something
        }
    };

    (@success $fn_name:ident, $shape:expr, $axis:expr, $ans:expr) => {
        #[test]
        impl_test!($fn_name, $shape, $axis, $ans)
    };

    (@panic $fn_name:ident, $shape:expr, $axis:expr, $ans:expr) => {
        #[test]
        #[should_panic]
        impl_test!($fn_name, $shape, $axis, $ans)
    };
}
```

It does not work with the following error.

Comment: You did not include the error

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `{}` or follow the invocation by `;` for macros that expand to items. And you have to pass the attributes forward like explaned in [Apply attribute to macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54938004/442760)

```rust
macro_rules! impl_test {
    ($(#[$m:meta])* $fn_name:ident) => {
        $(#[$m])*
        fn $fn_name() {
            // do something
            println!("{}", stringify!($fn_name));
        }
    };

    (@success $fn_name:ident) => {
        impl_test!{
            #[test]
            $fn_name
        }
    };

    (@panic $fn_name:ident) => {
        impl_test!{
            #[test]
            #[should_panic]
            $fn_name
        }
    };
}

impl_test!(bare_function);
impl_test!(@success successful_test);
impl_test!(@panic panicing_test);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `{}`, but you need a semicolon if you don't.